# How do I print main_menu?

Tags: 7

I try to render a main menu but it doesn't render. My old Drupal 6 template try to upgrade Drupal 7 template.

I've render in page.tpl.php.

```
<?php if (isset($main_menu)) : ?>
    <?php print phptemplate_primary($main_menu); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the code for `phptemplate_primary()`.

```
function phptemplate_primary() {
  $output = '<div id="primary-links-region">';
  $element = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_primary_links_source', 'primary-links'));
  $output .= drupal_render($element);
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it both ways:

1. You can add menu block to your template - just like any other block (this method is the easiest).
2. If you need more customization, you can do it in template:

page.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($primary_nav): print $primary_nav; endif; ?>
```

template.php

```
if (isset($variables['main_menu'])) {
  $variables['primary_nav'] = theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
    'links' => $variables['main_menu'],
    'attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'main-menu'),
    ),
    'heading' => array(
      'text' => t('Main menu'),
      'level' => 'h2',
      'class' => array('element-invisible'),
    )
  ));
}
else {
  $variables['primary_nav'] = FALSE;
}
```